# How to use AirPods as a hearing aid?

Tags: airpods

Can I use AirPods as a hearing aid?

Comment: Apple says no, AirPods cannot take the place of traditional hearing aids. Although Live Listen may help users hear sounds more clearly, people with moderate to severe hearing loss will probably not benefit much from it.

Comment: @DManokhin - how about making this an answer, with appropriate citations??

Comment: @Tetsujin The information I have found is not on apples website and is not an appropriate citation

Comment: I’ve seen an aid that plugged into earbuds. Basically, you point a stick at a specific conversation and it blocks other noise. It’s not perfect but it’s pretty cool.

Comment: There's a broad overview of "hearable technology" at https://www.everydayhearing.com/hearing-technology/articles/hearables/ . A recent product is Bose Hearphones, which you should be able to try in their company stores.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the Live Listen feature on iOS.

> With Live Listen, your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch becomes a remote
> microphone that sends sound to your Made for iPhone hearing aid. Live
> Listen can help you hear a conversation in a noisy room or hear
> someone speaking across the room.
>
> 1. Tap Settings > General > Accessibility > MFi Hearing Devices.
> 2. Tap your hearing aid under Devices.
> 3. Tap Start Live Listen.
> 4. Place the device in front of the person you want to hear.

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203990